# Convert VarBinary back into a pdf document

Tags: sql, vb.net, pdf, binary

I am trying to convert the VarBinary data that is in a MS SQL database back into a pdf document.  The binary data is at the location of https://app.box.com/s/nstjvp64zlurqbk1k8ruks3s74ujvdry.

The hex file starts with:

```
%PDF-1.6
%âãÏÓ
336 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/First 289/Length 1139/N 36/Type/ObjStm>>stream
```

The complete file is located at  https://app.box.com/s/x04flnhuwp6m1inc61vx8rb322llf395

I can convert the binary into a file but then the Abode Reader says it's damaged.  I think the step that I'm missing is the "decompression"?? But

The simple code that I'm using is:

```
    Dim b As Byte() = UnicodeStringToBytes(input.Text)
    Dim fs As IO.FileStream = New IO.FileStream("test.pdf", IO.FileMode.Create)

    fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
    fs.Close()
```

Comment: The input hex file looks to be truncated. PDF files normally end in `%%EOF`, but I get similar results to your file after decoding. It's ending in the middle of an object `<261 0 objj << ... >> ...(binary data)`. Check that your input file is complete.

Comment: Thanks for the help- I'll see what I can do

Comment: does this help?  https://app.box.com/s/x04flnhuwp6m1inc61vx8rb322llf395

Comment: That's also truncated.

Comment: 100% totally appreciate your help One more-- had to jump a few hoops so that the SQL data did not get truncated but learning as I go  https://app.box.com/s/aytt1t55aac3d9hy8rbn5lzlmytb6rq0

Comment: and different binary https://app.box.com/s/geev0b1shsu5a1c98zxcqi5gg4a5h46h

Comment: and one more https://app.box.com/s/q63xlrhorbqus1xx69plbi1y1vquzjwn

Comment: It's still truncating somehow. What to look for is '%%EOF" at the end of PDF file or or 2525454F46 at the end of the hex file (%%EOF converted to hex).